# Angular Bootstrap datepicker - date disabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an AngularUI Bootstrap calendar with a `disabledDates` function

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="date" ng-change="change()"  date-disabled="disabledDates(date,mode)"></uib-datepicker>
```

This is the function:

```
 $scope.disabledDates = function (date, mode) {
                if ($scope.daysAvailable != null) {
                    return mode === 'day' && $scope.daysAvailable.indexOf(date.getDay() + 1) == -1;
                }
            }
```

`$scope.daysAvailable` is loaded from the server with an `$http` request

```
 $scope.init = function () {
    return $http.get('/OrderEntry/GetAvailableDays', { params: { method: shipMethod, state: state, zip: zip } }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.daysAvailable  data.data;
    });
}
```

The problem is that my HTML is loading (and calling `disabledDates()` before the results are returned from the server and loaded in the controller `init()`

How can I prevent the calendar load until the data is returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can display the date picker only after daysAvailable arrive:

```
<div ng-show="daysAvailable">
    <uib-datepicker  ng-model="date" ng-change="change()"  date-disabled="disabledDates(date,mode)"></uib-datepicker>
</div>
```